# Disable command button until checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

i know this probs really simple, but all the answers i have found involve using javascript, and i am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

what i want to disable the confirm button untill the checkbox above is ticked, how can i do this, and then if it is ticked and unticked then it goes back to being disabled

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="Markconfirm"
                                              value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markingCompleted}"/>


                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:button id="back"
                          value="back"
                          outcome="/cohort-coordinator/marking/view-all-marks"
                          icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w"/>

                <p:commandButton id="confirm"
                                 value="Confirm"
                                 actionListener ="#{markingBean.editMark}"
                                 update=":growl"
                                 icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

Comment: I fear there is no way without using javascript `:/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ajax event to your checkbok that disable or enable  your boutton .

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="Markconfirm" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markingCompleted}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="confirm" /> 
 </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>


 <p:commandButton id="confirm"
                             value="Confirm"
                             disabled="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markingCompleted}"
                             actionListener ="#{markingBean.editMark}"
                             update=":growl"
                             icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that is working fine when it is ticked and i untick it the command button works, but not when it is unticked, the command button then is live and when ticked the command button is disabled, any ideas ?

Comment: @user2962401 Yes, the reason is `markingBean.markToEdit.markingCompleted` is not yet initialized when it is first called => `disabled="#{null}"`. So initialize it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Do it via Javascript as next:
add a widgetVar to your `<p:commandButton>` let's call it `confirmButtonWV`

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="confirmButtonWV" disabled="true" id="confirm" value="Confirm" actionListener ="#{markingBean.editMark}" update=":growl" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

and a widgetVar for your checkbox, let's call it `markConfirmWV`:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox widgetVar="markConfirmWV" id="Markconfirm" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markingCompleted}" />
```

Then use the next script:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     markConfirmWV.jq.on('click', function() {
         var confirmButton = confirmButtonWV.jq;
         if (confirmButton.is(":disabled")) {
              confirmButton.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
         } else {
              confirmButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
         }
     });
 });
 </script>
```